# How to create an extension to deal with multiple core data entities

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have two core data entities named `Car` and `Owner`, both, obviously `NSManagedObject` and as all core data entities, all are `@Observable` by default.

I have created a class where I was observing one of these entities, something like:

```
class RadioControlModel {

  @ObservedObject var carEntity:Car

  // ... bla bla

  init(_ carEntity:Car, _ name:String) {
    self.carEntity = readCarEntityWith(name)
  }
}
```

this class is the model of a radio control that allows the user to switch the state of a boolean value of the `Car` entity.

Now I need to do the same to the `Owner` entity, that is, to use this class to change a boolean value of this class but the `init` is tied to `Car`. How do I declare this as generic so `RadioControlModel` can accept any core data entity, not just of type `Car`.

My problem here is to do so and continue to have the variable `@Observable`, that is, responding to changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class RadioControlModel<T: NSManagedObject> {

  @ObservedObject var carEntity:T

  // ... bla bla

  init(_ carEntity:T, _ name:String) {
    self.carEntity = readCarEntityWith(name)
  }
}
```

Comment: ahhhhh, brilliant! Thanks

Comment: My pleasure! ✌️